# Spike: error while loading shared libraries: libriscv.so

Tags: riscv

I tried to execute spike this way by navigating to the folder the executable is in:

cd ~/riscv-tools/riscv-isa-sim/build
./spike
I get this error message:

./spike: error while loading shared libraries: libriscv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
It is significant that the file it claims to not find is in the same directory as the spike executable (in the build directory) - any help?

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic linker generally looks for shared libraries in predefined system directories such as /lib, /usr/lib as specified by ldconfig.

You can tell the linker to search in other directories with LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./spike
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to execute Spike it to execute it from the installed location, e.g. install it like this:

```
cd riscv-isa-sim
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=$HOME/local/riscv/spike
make
make install
```

And then execute it:

```
~/local/riscv/spike/bin/spike ...
```

No need to mess around with your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then (which really should be avoided, if possible).